# Execute request model binding manually

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In Asp.Net you can automatically parse request data into an input model / API contract using for example the attributes `FromBody`, `FromQuery`, and `FromRoute`. I want to execute this behavior myself. Let me explain.

I want to have a custom policy requirement based on a combination of data passed to the requirement and the target entity which is passed inside the request data. But this target entity id can be in different locations. Usually the body, but for example the route or the query when using `HttpGet`. So I thought about putting this information about the location above the controller endpoint using an attribute. The following pseudo-code is based on the guess that I need the `BindingSource`.

I would create API contracts using an interface defining the location of the target id.

```
public interface ITargetEntityContract {
    public string TargetEntityId { get; set; }
}

public class ExampleRequest : ITargetEntityContract {
    public string TargetEntityId { get; set; } = default!;
    public string SomeOtherData { get; set; } = default!;
}
```

Then I would create an attribute to define the location:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class TargetEntityLocationAttribute : Attribute {
    public Type ContractType { get; }
    public BindingSource BindingSource { get; }

    public TargetEntityLocationAttribute(Type contractType, BindingSource bindingSource) {
        if (!typeof(ITargetEntityContract).IsAssignableFrom(contractType))
            throw new Exception("Contract has to implement the interface ITargetEntityContract");

        this.ContractType = contractType;
        this.BindingSource = bindingSource;
    }
}
```

And you would apply this onto a controller endpoint the following way:

```
[TargetEntityLocation(typeof(ExampleRequest), BindingSource.Body)]
public async Task<IActionResult> SomeEndpointAsync([FromBody] ExampleRequest requestData) {
    
}
```

Within the `IAuthorizationHandler` I would use these classes the following way:

```
protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, ExampleAuthorizationRequirement requirement) {
    var endpoint = this._httpContextAccessor.HttpContext!.GetEndpoint();

    if (endpoint is null)
        throw new Exception("Some error");

    var targetEntityLocation = endpoint.MetaData.GetMetaData<TargetEntityLocationAttribute>();

    if (targetEntityLocation is null)
        throw new Exception("some error");
    
    var targetEntityModel = SomeAlmightyParser.ParseFromSource(this._httpContextAccessor.HttpContext!, targetEntityLocation.ContractType, targetEntityLocation.BindingSource) as ITargetEntityContract;
    
    // do something with targetEntityModel.TargetEntityId
}
```

Is there a way to parse the request data of the `HttpContext` into the given model based on the data location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a few years now, but here is the answer I came up with. NOTE: This code only works when executed within a project using the Sdk `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` since the `ModelBindingMelper`'s namespace is `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding` in the Web-Sdk but `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Internal` in the normal Sdk.

**Interface:**

```
public interface IRequestModelBinder {
    public class Result<TRequestModel> {
        public bool Succeeded { get; set; }
        public TRequestModel? Model { get; set; }
        public ModelStateDictionary ModelState { get; set; }
    }
    
    Task<Result<TRequestModel>> TryBindModelAsync<TRequestModel>() where TRequestModel : class, new();
    Task<Result<TRequestModel>> TryBindModelAsync<TRequestModel>(string prefix) where TRequestModel : class, new();
}
```

**Implementation:**

```
public class RequestModelBinder : IRequestModelBinder {
    public static readonly MethodInfo TryUpdateModelAsyncGenericMethodDefinition;
    
    protected IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor { get; }
    protected IApiDescriptionGroupCollectionProvider ApiDescriptionProvider { get; }
    protected MvcOptions Options { get; }

    static RequestModelBinder() {
        TryUpdateModelAsyncGenericMethodDefinition =
            Type.GetType("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelBindingHelper, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core")!
                .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
                .First(methodInfo =>
                    methodInfo.Name == "TryUpdateModelAsync" &&
                    methodInfo.IsGenericMethod &&
                    methodInfo.GetGenericArguments().Length == 1 &&
                    methodInfo.GetParameters().Length == 7
                );
    }
    
    public RequestModelBinder(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, IApiDescriptionGroupCollectionProvider apiDescriptionProvider, IOptions<MvcOptions> options) {
        this.HttpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        this.ApiDescriptionProvider = apiDescriptionProvider;
        this.Options = options.Value;
    }

    public async Task<IRequestModelBinder.Result<TRequestModel>> TryBindModelAsync<TRequestModel>() where TRequestModel : class, new() {
        return await this.TryBindModelAsync<TRequestModel>(string.Empty);
    }

    public async Task<IRequestModelBinder.Result<TRequestModel>> TryBindModelAsync<TRequestModel>(string prefix) where TRequestModel : class, new() {
        var actionDescriber = this.HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext!.Features.Get<IEndpointFeature>()?.Endpoint.Metadata.GetMetadata<ControllerActionDescriptor>()!;
        var actionContext = new ActionContext(
            this.HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext!,
            this.HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetRouteData(),
            actionDescriber
        );

        var controllerContext = new ControllerContext(actionContext) {
            ValueProviderFactories = this.Options.ValueProviderFactories
        };

        try {
            var valueProvider = await CompositeValueProvider.CreateAsync(controllerContext, controllerContext.ValueProviderFactories);
            var metaDataProvider = this.HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IModelMetadataProvider>();
            var modelBinderFactory = this.HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IModelBinderFactory>();
            var objectValidator = this.HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IObjectModelValidator>();
            
            /////////////////Try binding body source////////////////////////
            if (actionDescriber.Parameters.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ParameterType == typeof(TRequestModel))?.BindingInfo.BindingSource == BindingSource.Body) {
                var apiDescriptions = this.ApiDescriptionProvider.ApiDescriptionGroups.Items
                    .SelectMany(group => group.Items)
                    .ToList();
                
                var actionApiDescription = apiDescriptions
                    .First(description => description.ActionDescriptor.DisplayName == actionDescriber.DisplayName);

                var actionContentType = new ContentType(actionContext.HttpContext.Request.ContentType);
                var apiFormat = actionApiDescription.SupportedRequestFormats
                    .First(format => format.MediaType == actionContentType.MediaType);

                var streamPosition = actionContext.HttpContext.Request.Body.Position;
                if (actionContext.HttpContext.Request.Body.CanSeek)
                    actionContext.HttpContext.Request.Body.Position = 0;
                
                var result = await apiFormat.Formatter.ReadAsync(new InputFormatterContext(
                    actionContext.HttpContext,
                    string.Empty,
                    actionContext.ModelState,
                    metaDataProvider.GetMetadataForType(typeof(TRequestModel)),
                    (stream, encoding) => new StreamReader(stream, encoding)));
                
                if (actionContext.HttpContext.Request.Body.CanSeek)
                    actionContext.HttpContext.Request.Body.Position = streamPosition;
                
                return new IRequestModelBinder.Result<TRequestModel> {
                    Succeeded = result.IsModelSet && !result.HasError,
                    Model = (TRequestModel)result.Model,
                    ModelState = actionContext.ModelState
                };
            }
            
            /////////////////Try binding any other source///////////////////
            actionContext.ModelState.Clear();
            var tryUpdateModelAsyncDelegate = TryUpdateModelAsyncGenericMethodDefinition.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TRequestModel));

            var model = new TRequestModel();
            var bindingSucceeded = await (Task<bool>) tryUpdateModelAsyncDelegate.Invoke(null, new object?[] {
                model,
                prefix,
                controllerContext,
                metaDataProvider,
                modelBinderFactory,
                valueProvider,
                objectValidator
            })!;
            
            return new IRequestModelBinder.Result<TRequestModel> {
                Succeeded = bindingSucceeded,
                Model = model,
                ModelState = actionContext.ModelState
            };
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            return new IRequestModelBinder.Result<TRequestModel> {
                Succeeded = false,
                Model = null,
                ModelState = new ModelStateDictionary()
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the source of the data is RequestBody,you could read the stream with StreamReader and deserialize the string you get;

If the source of the data is RequestQuery,you could map the key-value pairs to your target object with reflection

For example,I tried as below:

```
                //read obj from requestbody
                using var reader = new StreamReader(context.Request.Body);  
                var bodystr = reader.ReadToEndAsync().Result;
                if (bodystr != "")
                {
                    var obj1 = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(bodystr, typeof(ExampleRequest), new JsonSerializerOptions() { });
                }
               

                //read simple obj from query
                var querycollection = context.Request.Query;
                var type = typeof(ExampleRequest);               
                var properties = type.GetProperties();
                object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                foreach (var propinfo in properties)
                {
                    var propname = propinfo.Name;
                    if (querycollection.ContainsKey(propname))
                    {
                        var proptype = propinfo.PropertyType;
                        propinfo.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(querycollection[propname].ToString(), proptype),null);                        
                    }                    
                }
                var obj2 = obj as ExampleRequest;
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I know how to parse body or query data. But these are not the only sources. There are still route, form, form files, headers, ... So I want to execute model binding which already implements all these sources instead of reimplementing it myself.

Comment: Model binding can be invoked manually by using the TryUpdateModelAsync method  as you described (but just in controller), and there are no other methods  could be invoked in your handler provied as far as I known